# How to consume asp.net webapi with knockout

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am new to knockout and asp.net webapi, but I am trying to learn.  I am missing something, as i cannot perform a get(or a post,put...)
here is my webapi method

```
public  string GetAllData()
{
    List<Task> llistTask = new  List<Task>();
    Task lobjTask = new Task();
    lobjTask.title = "some title";
    lobjTask.isDone = false;

    llistTask.Add(lobjTask);

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(llistTask);

}
```

my knockout code

```
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
            <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
           <h3>Tasks</h3>

        <form data-bind="submit: addTask">
            Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>

            <ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
                <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
                <input data-bind="value: title" />
              <%--  <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>--%>
            </li> 
        </ul>

        You have <b data-bind="text: incompleteTasks().length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
        <span data-bind="visible: incompleteTasks().length == 0"> - it's beer time!</span>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                function Task(data) {
                    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
                    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
                }

                function TaskListViewModel() {
                    // Data
                    var self = this;
                    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
                    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
                    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function () {
                        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function (task) { return !task.isDone() });
                    });

                    // Operations
                    self.addTask = function () {
                        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
                        self.newTaskText("");
                    };
                    self.removeTask = function (task) { self.tasks.remove(task) };

                    // Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
                    $.getJSON("http://localhost:51958/api/tasks/GetAllData", function (allData) {
                        var mappedTasks =  $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Task(item) });
                        self.tasks(mappedTasks);


                    });
                }

                ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());


            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The output is   39 rows of null data, which doesnt make sense to me.  what am i missing?

Comment: I updated my answer below to eliminate the real source of the problem, and not to cure the symptoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the handling results of the `$.getJSON()` function. It returns you a string, not a JSON object, and when you do `$.map()` later you're iterating 39 characters of your string, but not the objects you need.

To fix it you need to parse your string as a JSON:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:51958/api/tasks/GetAllData", function (allData) {
    allData = $.parseJSON(allData);
    var mappedTasks =  $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Task(item) });
    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
});
```

## Update:

I was really interested, why do you get a string instead of a real object as you should get in case of `$.getJSON()` function. And the reason is your WebApi method. As far as it returns a string, WebAPI engine converts it additionally to a JSON string (it doesn't care that you've already done it). As a result you have twice JSONified object and jQuery can't parse it.

All you need to do is to return not a `string` but a `List<Task>` in your WebAPI method and not to JSON it:

```
public List<Task> GetAllData()
{
    List<Task> llistTask = new  List<Task>();
    ...
    return llistTask;
}
```

And you can leave your JS code as you had it (no additional `parseJSON`), because now you'll get a real object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [ko.mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  It puts the individual objects in form knockout likes.

code would look like

```
    // initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:51958/api/tasks/GetAllData", function (allData) {

                self.tasks = ko.mapping.fromJSON(allData);
    });
```

Comment: Tried it, but it bring back data. hmm