# How can I access a Class that holds a function with knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

How do I access  the methods and properties of a class that doesn't have an api registered in knockout?

I have a method in a class RoomBookingVM

```
  public void FindRoomFromDates(DateTime BookingFrom, DateTime BookingTo, int GuestNumbers) { etc }
```

I need to run it passing through variables self.DateFrom.value, self DateTo.value and self.NumberOfGuests. which I can populate on the page.

I eventually need to return back a property  list OutputAllRoomCosts from the same class which I will then iterate through on the page as well.

I am not even sure how to start this. Sorry for being so vague, everything I have read is simple CRUD via the api's. If its not in the api, how do I access it?

edit:

My problem is having the terminology to explain what I want. :-)

I have a project created for windows Forms with an entity DB that I am moving over to ASP.net mvc and Knockout. In the project I have a class which holds a method that calculates the free rooms in a motel based on guests booking dates and numbers.

Now the basic CRUD from the entity db was automatically scaffolded and turned into API's that I can access with Knockout.

However the Class and its important method misses out on this transformation to an API.

So what I want is a way to connect the method through to the view using knockout if it doesn't have an api, or alternatively to generate an API for the method.

The FindRoomFromDates(DateTime BookingFrom, DateTime BookingTo, int GuestNumbers)  method takes the 3 parameters I need but doesn't output, instead I return data via a list that is a property of the class.

Comment: using `ajax` you can call and fill the view with Model data from server

Comment: What have you tried? How does your current view model and view look like? How does the clasee look like?

Comment: Updated my post :-) I spend most of the day trying to get the method tied into knockout, without success.

Answer (score 0):

From you question, I understand that you are trying to consume a asp.net web api method from knockout. If my understanding is right, these links should help you

[How to consume asp.net webapi with knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557302/how-to-consume-asp-net-webapi-with-knockout)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755386/Jumpstart-KnockoutJS-with-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-Api

Comment: Thanks Kumards, however the method doesn't have an api. that is my problem. How do I create an api for a method? The CRUD was automatically generated but this is a specific method in its own class that I moved from a Forms application. There must be a common way of doing this :-)